# How to set icon properties in Kubuntu 11.10 launcher?

Tags: 11.10, launcher, kubuntu

I have some scripts:
  chrome-aoeu@gmail.com
  chrome-ueoa@netflix.com

that open Chrome with specific --user-data-dir settings.  When I drag the icons into launcher, the icon launches Chrome, but it does so to a specific site (the first one opens up GMail and the second one opens up Netflix).

Comment: could you post the content of your script files?

Comment: # chrome-aoeu@gmail.com
google-chrome --user-data-dir=${HOME}/.config/google-chrome/aoeu@gmail.com

# chrome-ueoa@netflix.com
google-chrome --user-data-dir=${HOME}/.config/google-chrome/ueoa@netflix.com

# idea
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_25 /opt/idea-IU/bin/idea.sh

Answer (score 1):

I used gnome-desktop-item-edit as described at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfTfc-DLtpU to create a .desktop file. Then I used Dash home to search for the app and dragged-and-dropped the icon into the launcher.